# Webpack when run in terminal it gives an "error error: unknown option '-p'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, module

I wanted to run Webpack using **npm run build** but it gives an error in the terminal

```
error: unknown option '-p'
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
C:\React Projects\Webpack\Project>
```

[image]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "watch": "webpack --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Looks like it was updated to be `--mode production` in a recent release.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/1934

Comment: this worked for me. changed my webpack command in package.json from `webpack -p --env production` to `webpack --mode production --env production`